# github3.py Repository class is there a way to "Create" a branch?

Tags: python, github, github-api, github3.py

Using version 1.0.0a4 of the github3.py library.

I am trying to create a new file in the repository on a new branch.

Assumption:  **gh** is an authenticated object.

```
repo = gh.repository('User','Repo')
repo.create_file(path='NewFile',message='Commit Message',content='File Content', branch='NewBranch')
```

The call to create_file fails to create the 'NewFile' and the 'NewBranch'.
If I do the following the file is created ok on the "Default" branch as I would expect.

```
repo.create_file(path='NewFile',message='Commit Message',content='File Content')
```

I was sure that the first form of the 'create_file' did in fact create the branch once, but I'm unsure why it isn't happening now.  Is it not a fair expectation that the 'branch' would be created by this call?  I haven't found another API that would create a branch.

Comment: Since "The call to create_file fails to create the 'NewFile' and the 'NewBranch'" could you add the stack trace?

Comment: @Hipny traceback? But, yes, anyway

Comment: The call itself doesn't fail, that seems to work just fine, but the actions expected don't happen.  I don't seem to get much of a helpful error back from github3.py as well.

Comment: Ok, looks like the create_file doesn't support the creation of the branches.  Needed to use the `create_ref` method and give it the new **reference** `refs/heads/new_branch` and then it was created.  I can now use that new branch and create the new file there.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.2.0 you can use [`Repository.create_branch_ref`](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.repo.Repository.create_branch_ref):

```
repo = gh.repository('User','Repo')
repo.create_branch_ref('NewBranch')
repo.create_file(path='NewFile',message='Commit Message',content='File Content', branch='NewBranch')
```

By default the branch will be forked off the default branch (usually main / master), but you can also supply a sha to specify the exact fork point.